# An api is returning pdf in text form how to save it as pdf?

Tags: java, flutter, api, dart

I am working on a flutter project in which the API returns PDF. But it is in the form of text like this

```
%PDF-1.4 1 0 obj << /Title (��) /Creator(��) /Producer(��)
```

How can I save it as a `.pdf`.

Comment: Those are the bytes in the pdf.  Just save them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download a file using http.post with url encoded body in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571306/how-to-download-a-file-using-http-post-with-url-encoded-body-in-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API is basically returning you bytes. Just write those bytes directly to a file usinng java.nio.Files class or FileOutputStream as you like.
Remember to not convert bytes to String as it may affect the encoding and charset, possibly corrupting your file